# indexOf is not a function error while focusing on an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('input').focusout(function() {

  if ($(this).indexOf('@') > -1 && $(this).indexOf('.') > -1) {
    $('.status').html('Valid Email');
  } else {
    $('.status').html('Your email is invalid, Please try again');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="email" placeholder="Email">
<p class="status"></p>
```

When I focus out from input area, it gives error `indexOf is not a function`.

Comment: `$(this).val().indexOf` Also if your aim is email validation, consider regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you should consider in your solution.

1. **`$(this)` will refer to its parent which is in your particular case it is `$('input')`**. So if you want to check whether `@` or `.` exists in your input value, you should refer to [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method within your query, so it will return the current value of your input.

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
$('input').focusout(function() {

  if ($(this).val().indexOf('@') > -1 && $(this).val().indexOf('.') > -1) {
    $('.status').html('Valid Email');
  } else {
    $('.status').html('Your email is invalid, Please try again');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="email" placeholder="Email">
<p class="status"></p>
```

2. Whilst **your solution** for checking special symbols in email working fine it **won't check the entire input characters**. So **the best way** (best practice) **to check such a thing is to using [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)**. Thus you should create a proper regex with either [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) or *regular expression literals*.

So your final code would be like this:

```js
const emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

$('input').focusout(function() {
  if (emailRegex.test($(this).val())) {
    $('.status').html('Valid Email');
  } else {
    $('.status').html('Your email is invalid, Please try again');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="email" placeholder="Email">
<p class="status"></p>
```